# error using find() while determining coordinates to calculate slope of a line in the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Im extracting frames from video and plotting the slope value for the coordinates obtained in each line detected in each frame like below

Am plotting the "slope" value against "frames".

Extracting frames from video

```
for k = 1 :240 %no.of frames
%Here in loop am extracting the line from each frame then 
[ycoord,xcoord]=find(line);%finding the coordinates of line
Ymax(k)=max(ycoord); 
Ymin(k)=min(ycoord); 
Xmax(k)=max(xcoord); 
Xmin(k)=min(xcoord); 
slope(k)=(Ymax(k)-Ymin(k)/Xmax(k)-Xmin(k));
end; 
plot(slope,'-ro');%plotting slope values of frames
```

But when there is no line found in a frame then find(line) is giving empty arrays and there is no slope calculated showing error .
  My requirement is when there is no line in the next frame then the slope value should be zero else it should calculate the slope value.
can some one please help on this

Comment: I think there is a small bug in your code.

`slope(k)=(Ymax(k)-Ymin(k)/Xmax(k)-Xmin(k));`

should be:

`slope(k)=((Ymax(k)-Ymin(k))/(Xmax(k)-Xmin(k)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your code, but in general, when find can't find something, it returns an empty matrix. You can use the `isempty` function to test if this is the case and manually set `ycoord` and `xcoord` to values that won't cause an error on.

[isempty() MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isempty.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes now it is working                                `if((isempty(xcoord)=1) && (isempty(xcoord)=1))
     then
    caluclate slope
    else
     slope=0;
    end`

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize the code:

```
lines=[0,0,0,0,0,0; %# lines for example
       0,0,1,2,3,0;
       0,3,4,5,0,0];
lines(:,:,2)=[0,0,0,0,0,0;
              0,0,0,0,0,0;
              0,0,0,0,0,0];
bool_mask = double(lines ~= 0);
bool_mask(bool_mask == 0) = NaN; %# for later min function
[row_grid, col_grid] = ndgrid(1:size(lines,1), ...
                              1:size(lines,2), ....
                              1:size(lines,3));
min_row = squeeze(min(min(row_grid .* bool_mask,[],1)));
max_row = squeeze(max(max(row_grid .* bool_mask,[],1)));
min_col = squeeze(min(min(col_grid .* bool_mask,[],2)));
max_col = squeeze(max(max(col_grid .* bool_mask,[],2)));
slope = (max_row-min_row)./(max_col-min_col);
slope(isnan(slope)) = 0; %# x/0 is NaN, and absent line is NaN. Turn to 0.
slope
```

Gives output:

```
slope =

    0.3333
         0
```